# How to use sed within python?

Tags: javascript, python, sed

I am sure there must be more intelligent way to achieve this. I need to change the app id in my javascript BEFORE minifying it with Closure.

One "quick" solution I came up with, was using the good old sed. While this works on command line, it fails when run within a python file.  It doesn't fail with an error. The outfile file is the exact copy of the source. As if it hasn't found the text.

```
choice = raw_input("Type 1 (Staging) or 2 (Production)?")
   if choice == '1':
        cmd = r"sed 's%var appid = '1234';%var appid = '5678';%' {0}f11.js > {0}f11_final.js".format(PATH)
        os.system(cmd)
```

Any idea what I am missing? Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I just changed the source from this:

```
var appid = '1';
```

to this:

```
var appid = 1;
```

and ran this successfully:

```
cmd = "sed -i 's%var appid = 1;%var appid = 2;%' {0}f11.js".format(PATH)
```

It has to do with escaping single quotes.  Any idea what I could do? I tried `\'` but it fails.

**Solution:**

I ended up doing it in python as suggested. It is not easy though, if you haven't done it before.  So I share my code:

```
with open("{0}f11.js".format(PATH), "r") as sources:
    lines = sources.readlines()
with open("{0}f11-final.js".format(PATH), "w") as sources:
    for line in lines:
        sources.write(re.sub("var appid = '1';", "var appid = '2';", line))
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `'` inside the regex be escaped?

Comment: Are you sure? This works for me - os.system(r"echo 'var appid = 1234;' |  sed 's%var appid = '1234';%var appid = '5678';%'")

Comment: It throws `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string` if I escape it like that: `cmd = r"sed 's%var appid = \'1234\';%var appid = \'5678\';%' ...`

Comment: @user1827356 have you tried it s a file? I just verified it a few times without luck

Comment: Works fine with Python 2.7.1 and GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)

Comment: @user1827356  you are not doing exactly what I do. Your source is a number, not string.  Please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the library [re](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) of Python. In particular the function sub that is similar to sed.